Exploiting this code in order to change grade into an A+
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
  I obtained access to the professor's grade management program.
  Can I change my grade to an 'A' and also get access to the shell?
*/

typedef struct Student_{
    char name[40];
    char passcode[4];
    int student_number;
    char grade[4];
}Student;

void menu(Student *student);
void input(Student *student);
void print_info(Student *student);
void graduate_school_application(Student *student);
void init_passcode(Student *student);

void menu(Student *student){
    int num;
    printf("1: Input\n2: Print info\n3: graduate_school_application\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
  if(num==1) input(student);
  else if(num==2) print_info(student);
  else if(num==3) graduate_school_application(student);
  else printf("num error\n");
  return;
}


void input(Student *student){
  char passcode[4];
  printf("enter below informations.\n\n");
  printf("[student number]\n");
  scanf("%d", &student->student_number);
  printf("[name]\n");
  read(0, student->name, 40);
  printf("[grade]\n");
  read(0, student->grade, 5);
  if(strncmp(student->grade, "A+", 2) == 0){
    printf("To award an A+ grade, please enter the passcode:\n");
    read(0, passcode, 4);
    if(strncmp(student->passcode, passcode, 4) != 0){
      printf("Error. You will get F grade.\n");
      strcpy(student->grade, "F");
    }
  }
}

void print_info(Student *student){
   printf("name : %s\n", student->name);
   printf("student number : %d\n", student->student_number);
}

void graduate_school_application(Student *student){
  if(strncmp(student->grade, "A+", 2)){
  printf("You need to have an A+ grade to apply to the graduate 
         school\n");
  return;
  }
  printf("Congratulation! you can apply graduate school ^^\n");
  printf("Please enter your name\n");
  read(0, student->name, 100);
  printf("Well done. I'll text you soon.\n");
  printf("And... this is present for you.\n");
  printf("%p\n", &student->name);
  return;
}

void init_passcode(Student *student){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<4; i++){
        student->passcode[i] = rand()%256;
    }
}

int main(){
    int i;
    Student student = {"", "", 0, ""};

    setvbuf(stdin, 0, _IONBF, 0);   // Function for setting up remote. You don't need to care about it when solving the problem.
    setvbuf(stdout, 0, _IONBF, 0);   // Function for setting up remote. You don't need to care about it when solving the problem.

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    printf("[Professor's grade management program]\n\n");

    init_passcode(&student);
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        menu(&student);
    }
    return 0;
}

I tried a buffer overflow with the grade variable since it can read an extra byte than the actual length but the extra byte ends up counting as my input for the passcode. ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎  ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎  ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎  ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎  ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎  ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎

"the extra byte ends up counting as my input for the passcode" - now think of how strncmp works for the grade comparison and the passcode comparison.

You should probably get into the habit of checking the return value from scanf to ensure it actually succeeded.

Since you have access to the source code there's no need to "exploit" anything... just change it and rebuild.

The grade buffer overflow is not the way to exploit this program. Instead, look closely at menu item #2.

@Lundin The idea is to exploit an instance that runs on a remote server via a telnet connection or something like that. You can run a changed copy on your own machine but that won't do you any good.

@n.m.couldbeanAI And the complete source of that program was obtained how, exactly?

@Lundin I dunno, undeleted from a thumb drive found in a parking lot? It's an exercise.

The extra byte isn't treated as the first byte of your passcode input, it overflows into the first byte of student->passcode. If this byte is zero, student->passcode becomes an empty string.
Then all you have to do is provide an empty string as your passcode input, by entering a null byte as the first character.
In Python, you can then send:
r.send(b'A+\0X\0\0xxx')

A+\0X fills in student->grade; the \0 is the null terminator of the string. The next \0 overflows into the first byte of student->passcode, making it an empty string. The final \0xxx is read into passcode; since it begins with a null byte, it's also an empty string. Since both student->passcode and passcode are now empty strings, strncmp(student->passcode, passcode, 4) will indicate that they're equal, and you'll pass the authentication.

Am i overflowing the name variable or the grade variable? because I don't think the passcode is below the grade in the stack

Not the stack, the structure. Notice that it reads the grade directly into student->grade, not a local variable.

So it overflows into student->passcode, which changes the passcode that your next input is compared with.

i have it set up so r.send(b'A+++\0') is inputted for student->grade but it doesn't seem to effect student->passcode

It should be r.send(b'A+\0+\0'). You need to terminate the A+ string with a null byte.

If you're using Python instead of a terminal, all my <nul> should be \0.

I then r.send(b' ') when asked for the passcode and it says still says error

You still don't get it. Everywhere that I say <nul> in my answer should be \0 in Python. So that should be r.send(b'\0xxx')

I've updated my answer with the necessary code.

grade cannot overflow passcode, they are not adjacent in the struct.

Oops, I misread the struct definition.

I'm trying to delete this answer, but I've run into a SO bug that occasionally fails deletions.
